# Could not load file or assembly 'AutoMapper' in .net project

Tags: sql, database, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

> Could not load file or assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=6.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have two projects: Azure Function Project and Library project. The library project is where the database tables, context defined in it which running .Net Core 2.0 whereas the Azure Function Project run on .Net Framework 4.6.1.

The error occurred when calling the

```
db.ExecuteProcedureQuery<ApiAttendanceModel>(StoredProcedureName.Sp_GetAttendanceByAttendanceId, out error, parameterList).SingleOrDefault();
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Why not running Azure Functions on .Net Core?

Comment: because I have issue with using the azure table inside azure function coz it doesn't support yet which I have asked in stackoverflow before.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean, that you're unable to use `Table Storage` bindings with the new runtime?

Comment: Inside the azure function (trigger by queue), tried to connect to azure table in the code. It fired and exception. So I changed the project back to .net standard 4.6.1

Comment: At this stage, instead of using store procedure. I use linq-to-sql way to do it. I know it was a not efficient way but just tried it first.

Comment: You might be running into this issue trying to reference assemblies from both .net core and .net framework: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Inside the azure function (trigger by queue), tried to connect to azure table in the code. It fired and exception. So I changed the project back to .net standard 4.6.1

AFAIK, [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/) depends on [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/) which would depends on [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).
Per my test, I could leverage the client SDK to work with Azure Table storage under my Azure Functions v2.

If your Azure Function targets .NET Framework v4.6.1, after you references the Net Core 2.0 class library, your Azure Function project would retrieve the compile errors as follows:

[image]

For your scenario, I would recommend you create a class library targets the .Net Standard that allows your library to be called by your Azure Functions v1 (.NET Framework) or Azure Functions v2 (.NET Core). Details you could follow [Building a .NET Standard class library with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio#creating-a-class-library-solution).

Moreover, I just created my .Net Standard 1.3 class library to test this issue. You need to choose which .Net Standard version to be targeted, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).